# My user defaults are not saving my slider value - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsuserdefaults, uislider

I am creating a pomodoro timer app and I'm currently trying to implement user defaults in a slide up menu (Settings class), which is responsible for containing uisliders for adjusting the length of the timer. The user defaults looks pretty correct to me but whenever I close the app in the simulator and reopen it the value doesn't save? The slider and the label both go back to their default values. what am I doing wrong?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Settings: UIView {

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

let durationSlide = "durationSlide"


@IBOutlet weak var durationSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var durationLabel: UILabel!

func viewDidLoad() {

    if let durationSlide = defaults.value(forKey: durationSlide) {
        durationSlider.value = durationSlide as! Float
        durationSliderValueChanged(durationSlider)
    }


}


@IBAction func durationSliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let currentValue = Int(sender.value)
    durationLabel.text = "\(currentValue) minutes"
    defaults.set(sender.value, forKey: durationSlide)
}
```

Comment: Use `defaults.float(forKey: durationSlide)`

Comment: Your `Settings` class is implemented as a `UIView`, not a`UIViewController`. So, its method `viewDidLoad()` is not automatically called. Call it explicitly when you instantiate your `Settings`, or define initializers of `Settings` and call `viewDidLoad()` (the name should be changed...) from inside the initializers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the proper pair of methods to set and get your value in `UserDefaults`

You are saving the value with `defaults.set(sender.value, forKey: durationSlide)` which is saving a `Float` in `UserDefaults`.

But your attempt to read the value is using the wrong method. You are using `value(forKey:)` which isn't a method of `UserDefaults`. It's from the key-value coding extension to `NSObject` (which `UserDefaults` extends). Instead, use:

```
durationSlide = defaults.float(forKey: durationSlide)
```

This will give a value of `0` if there is no value in `UserDefaults`.